# Insert into....select query returning blank

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute the following command through straight sql execution and it runs fine without any errors but it's not actually working.

```
INSERT INTO log_inventory(CREATED_TIME, PRODUCT_ID, LOG_INV_CHANGE, LOG_INV_ACTION, LOG_INV_NUM_HISTORY, USER_ID)
SELECT now(), p.PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_INVENTORY, 'Manual Inventory Override', 0, 1
FROM product AS p WHERE p.PRODUCT_INVENTORY != 0;
```

The select query works because if I run that separately, it returns all the rows I need, but the insert portion doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: What client are you testing this in? The syntax is all correct.

Comment: InnoDB Mysql, running the sql query inside phpmyadmin and it shows no errors.

Comment: This is one of those things where you just need to quadruple check that you're working with the right db connection and the table has rows in it. Does the target table already have some rows, or is it empty?

Comment: Like I said, the select works and returns rows, the target table is empty though. I am definitely working in the right database, especially because I'm in phpmyadmin and it's hard not to be.

Comment: Wow, idk what I was doing wrong, I think it was just me being tired, it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the query has results, try this:

```
INSERT INTO log_inventory(CREATED_TIME, PRODUCT_ID, LOG_INV_CHANGE, LOG_INV_ACTION, LOG_INV_NUM_HISTORY, USER_ID)
(
    SELECT now(), p.PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_INVENTORY, 'Manual Inventory Override', 0, 1
    FROM product AS p 
    WHERE p.PRODUCT_INVENTORY != 0
);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It was working all along, idk what I was doing wrong. Since your comment made me try again, I'll mark it as answered, sorry!